# Update stock table through the invoice table in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have three tables which are `customer`, `stock`,`invoice`.

```
customer table PK is CNo(Customer No)
stock table PK is PNo(Product NO)
```

invoice table gets the both PKs(CNo from `customer` table and PNo from `stock` table) as Its Associate key .

What I want to do is , update stock table `QuntyAvailable` column through `invoice` table.

Ex. when a customer gets 2 Quantities from `PNo` 2 which is Dettol , it automatically update stock table `QuntyAvailabl`e column for above product's own row to 18( `QuntyAvailable-Qty`).

I tried many times with various queries but I got only errors. like PK cannot be Updated ..
bla bla bla......

Please help me on this Thank you.

```
customer table

CNo(PK)   | Name        | Address
1         | Jhon        | 23, Hill St, NY.
2         | Sam         | 24, Bejin , Chaina.
3         | Nic         | 25, London ,England.


stock table

PNo(PK)  | Description   | Each Price  | QntyAvailable
1        | Dettol        | $2          |   10
2        | Astra         | $5          |   20


invoice table

CNo(PK)    | PNo(PK)    | Qty      | value
1          | 2          | 2        | $10
2          | 1          | 3        | $6
```

after the update done I want the stock table like this...

```
 stock table

PNo(PK)  | Description   | Each Price  | QntyAvailable
1        | Dettol        | $2          |   7
2        | Astra         | $5          |   18
```

Please help me .. I m using mysql server and netbeans IDE

My query -------------

s.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO invoice(CNo,PNo,Qty,Value) VALUES('1','2','10','150')"); s.executeUpdate("UPDATE stock set QuntyAvailable=QuntyAvailable-10 WHERE Pno ='2'");

Comment: Thank you for posting your requirements. Now please post your attempt...

Comment: what are the query you have used so far?

Comment: s.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO invoice(CNo,PNo,Qty,Value) VALUES('1','2','10','150')");  s.executeUpdate("UPDATE stock set QuntyAvailable=QuntyAvailable-10 WHERE Pno ='2'");

Comment: I tried a lot with this code but I couldnt manage to solve the error. CODE -- CREATE TRIGGER UpdateStoock AFTER INSERT ON invoice FOR EACH ROW BEGIN UPDATE stock SET QntyAvailable=(QntyAvailable- new.Qty ) WHERE Pno =new.Pno   Error is "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1"    Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update stocks table when you do an insert in invoice, you can either do the update after the insert with the data you have for the insert (like the one you tried, the only thing that looks wrong is the `='2'` that looks like it should be only `=2`) or do it in a trigger, having the newly inserted values feed the update:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER updateStock AFTER INSERT ON invoice
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      UPDATE stock set QntyAvailable=QntyAvailable- new.Qty WHERE Pno =new.Pno;
  END;
//
```

You can check [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d8ad/1) to see it working.

P.S.

You really should have an InvoiceID. The way you are constructing it, you are not allowing a customer to purchase the same product twice.

P.S. 2 - Your error creating the trigger is related to not setting the DELIMITER.
If you don't set it the statement will end at the first ; You need to set it before the trigger and end your trigger definition with it. After that you can set the delimiter back to ;.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER updateStock AFTER INSERT ON invoice
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      UPDATE stock set QntyAvailable=QntyAvailable- new.Qty WHERE Pno =new.Pno;
  END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Just another heads up for the P.S. You really should add an invoiceID to invoice table. 
And if you end up finding that this helped solve your problem, don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: I tried a lot with this code but I couldnt manage to solve the error. CODE -- CREATE TRIGGER UpdateStoock AFTER INSERT ON invoice FOR EACH ROW BEGIN UPDATE stock SET QntyAvailable=(QntyAvailable- new.Qty ) WHERE Pno =new.Pno   Error is "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1"    Help

Comment: You are missing the END; and if you are using mysql console to create it, you have to put DELIMITER // before the CREATE TRIGGER and end it with //